# How do I run all nodes of Apache Ignite cluster from master node?

Tags: ignite

I have configured 4-node Apache Ignite Cluster. Now, I want to run all the nodes from master node<10.0.1.2> using a single command. I have tried to run using the following configuration, But it runs only one node. Any suggestion?

```
    **ignite.sh examples/config/myconf-ignite.xml**

     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
         <property name="addresses">
             <list>
                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                <value>10.0.1.2:47500..47509</value>
                <value>10.0.1.3:47500..47509</value>
                <value>10.0.1.4:47500..47509</value>
                <value>10.0.1.5:47500..47509</value>
             </list>
         </property>
      </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`startNodes`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCluster.html#startNodes-java.util.Collection-java.util.Map-boolean-int-int-) method after starting your "master" node (it will use SSH to connect to other servers and start processes there). Alternatively, you can just create a simple bash script that would do the same based on your specific requirements.

Note that in Ignite there is actually no concept of master node, Ignite follows share-nothing approach, and therefore all nodes are equal (at least by default).

Comment: So, Ignite dont have any option like Hadoop or Spark to run all node by just a command(start-all.sh)?

Comment: No, there is no such script included in Ignite.

Comment: can you provide sample script to use startNodes? I tried but failed.